# What is the current state of uncommitted changes called in git?

Tags: git

I sometimes use git diff like the following:

```
git diff staging..HEAD
```

What I'm wondering is whether there's a way to perform the same operation, but not against head, but against all the changes in the repo including the uncommited, unstaged ones. Akin to what `git diff` with no arguments does, but including the changes made by previous commit since branching off.

For example:

```
git diff staging..CURRENT
```

Comment: So you want to compare your current branch with the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you don't need to specify a name. You can just run `git diff staging` to compare `staging` to your current worktree.

From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> ***git diff* [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>...​]**
>
> This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree relative to the named <commit>. You can use HEAD to compare it with the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a different branch.